# переменная выводит undefined

Tags: javascript

есть два файла lib.js:

```
(function(){

var local = 100;

window.start = function(){
    return local++;
}

})();
```

и main.js:

```
console.log(window.local);
```

но когда обращаюсь к переменной local из файла main.js в консоли пишется undefined почему?

Comment: Таки непонятно что и зачем вы хотите сделать

Comment: в файле lib.js у меня анонимная функция, файлу main.js нужно предоставить доступ к переменной но без права ее изменения, то есть нужно чтобы в файле main.js было видно значение этой переменной, но ее нельзя делать глобальной чтобы нелльзя было менять ее значение через консоль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы определили переменную **local** в локальной области видимости. 
Вместо

```
var local = 100;
```

Напишите

```
window.local = 100;
```

И тогда она будет доступна глобально.

Comment: мне нужно сделать так чтобы к ней не было доступа извне но можно было получить ее значение из другого файла

Comment: @Banshee545 по-моему, первая и вторая части вашего предложения противоречат друг другу